# How to use OCaml Scanf module to parse a string containing integers separated by spaces WITHOUT Str

Tags: string, input, ocaml, whitespace

The title basically says it all. I am aware that through the use of regexp via OCaml's Str module, this task is quite simple - however, suppose you are only allowed to use the standard library and Scanf module. I am interested in taking a string looks like this:

```
    "12 34 555 6 23 34 5663 234 ..."
```

And returning an array that looks like this

```
  [|12; 34; 555; 6; 23; 34; 5663; 234; |]
```

Can someone help me out? I found the Scanf documentation (available http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Scanf.html) to be pretty unhelpful in understanding how to use the module

Comment: Any chance you could help me out @Virgile

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `Str`? It seems to be the common way to split a string into words in OCaml.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how idiomatic it is, but it works:

```
let parse_integers s =
  let stream = (Scanning.from_string s) in
  let rec do_parse acc =
    try
      do_parse (Scanf.bscanf stream " %d " (fun x -> x :: acc))
    with
      Scan_failure _ -> acc
    | End_of_file -> acc
  in Array.of_list (List.rev (do_parse []));;
```

A little test:

```
# parse_integers " 20 3 22";;
- : int array = [|20; 3; 22|]
```

(Update)

As explained in comments, the above code is not tail-recursive, whereas the following one is:

```
...
let rec do_parse acc = 
  match (Scanf.bscanf stream " %d " (fun x -> x :: acc)) 
with 
  | xs -> do_parse xs 
  | exception Scan_failure _ -> acc 
  | exception End_of_file -> acc
in ...
```

Comment: FWIW, `do_parse` is not tail-recursive because of the `try ... with ...` block. More details can be found [here](https://blogs.janestreet.com/pattern-matching-and-exception-handling-unite/). Something like this would solve that issue: `let rec do_parse acc =
    match (Scanf.bscanf stream " %d " (fun x -> x :: acc)) with
    | xs -> do_parse xs
    | exception Scan_failure _ -> acc
    | exception End_of_file -> acc`

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec f acc s =
  if s="" then
    Array.of_list (List.rev acc)
  else
    Scanf.sscanf s "%d %[^\n]" (fun n s-> f (n::acc) s)
;;



f [] "12 34 555 6 23 34 5663 234";;
# - : int array = [|12; 34; 555; 6; 23; 34; 5663; 234|]
```

Comment: I guess `sscanf` copies the rest of the string when applying `f (n::acc)` to (new) `s`, so the code's running time is O(n^2). This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39337946/2747511) is O(n).

Answer (score -1):

The format string for all the Scanf functions specifies a fixed number of values; thus, you can't expect to use a function from Scanf to read a variable number of values from a string.

If you break your string into pieces, you can use `Scanf.sscanf s "%d" (fun x -> x)` to translate each piece into an int. However, the function `int_of_string` is much simpler for that purpose.

I'd say you should start by breaking the string into pieces.